# Install Debian 32 or 64 bit, on weak hardware with a lightweight desktop environment

Tags: debian, xfce, desktop-environment, 64bit, 32bit

I'm planning to install a Debian 32-bit or 64-bit if possible.

It is a Toshiba Netbook NB305-N410BL-bn

The mfg specs list my Intel Atom® Processor N450
512K Cache, 1.66 GHz as a 64-bit processor

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42503/intel-atom-processor-n450-512k-cache-1-66-ghz.html#tab-blade-1-0

The computer specs show it as a 32-bit running windows 7 starter.

I don't know if this is the right distro, which installer, or if I should run 32 or 64-bit.

Comment: it's 64bit, personally I'd install 64bit OS

Comment: Morning, Doc. (Well, it is that here!) Probably an off-topic question as it's seeking an opinion. However, it does look like you'd be ok with a 64bit installation (try it and see, basically). Aim for a lightweight solution. Debian could be good but if you're a beginner maybe also consider Mint or Lubuntu. Good luck and enjoy!!

Comment: @roaima was faster :-D Seconding the lightweight distro recommendation - the CPU isn't very fast, and max RAM it supports is just 2GB. Another possible option is Zorin Lite, it's specifically aimed as an easy stepping-stone for Windows users.

Comment: Some (old but not very old) laptops are 64bit but with a 32bit UEFI firmware. You need a multi-arch installer for these: https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Support_for_mixed-mode_systems:_64-bit_system_with_32-bit_UEFI . Else you can install the 32 bits version, set the system multi-arch later and change everything (probably except GRUB) into 64 bits later... My own advice for simplicity: 32bit. 32bit consumes less memory and CPU speed doesn't matter when having to swap instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable input and time I do appreciate it. I'll check all of the above.  Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `debian gun/linux 64bit` and for a `lightweight desktop` solution you can use the `Xfce Desktop Environment`.

`Xfce` is one of the `fastest and very a lightweight` Desktop Environment.

`Xfce` also run on `raspberry`  very well and with `tails`  too.

> Xfce is a lightweight desktop environment for UNIX-like operating systems. It aims to be fast and low on system resources, while still being visually appealing and user friendly.

[Xfce Desktop Environment](https://www.xfce.org/?lang=en)

Comment: Well it's done lite 6.2 on a net book project.  works better than it ever did. Thanks for the help.